# Is there a web service that receives a reference and returns the impact factor?

Tags: website, impact-factor

Is there a web service that I can send a bibtex entry and receive an impact factor?

e.g.

```
http://magicalsite.com/query.php?json={MY_BIBTEX}
```

returns:

```
{
'IF':37.65
}
```

---

So I figured it out...

I use http://www.impactfactorsearch.com which is proposed in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/28330/15723).

Here's a quick and easy PHP script to get the impact factor of any journal:

```
<?php
$name        = "Applied Ocean Research"; //change to suit your needs
$journalName = urlencode($name);

$cmd      = "curl -s 'http://www.impactfactorsearch.com/test.php?json=true&input=$journalName'";
$result   = `$cmd`;
$ifObject = json_decode($result);

$levDistances = array();
if (isset($ifObject->results)) {
    if (is_array($ifObject->results) && (sizeof($ifObject->results) > 0)) {
        foreach ($ifObject->results as $journal) {
            $levDistances[$journal->value] = array(
                'score' => similar_text($journal->value, $journalName),
                'if' => $journal->id
            );
        }
        arsort($levDistances);
        $keys         = array_keys($levDistances);
        $impactFactor = doubleval($levDistances[$keys[0]]['if']);
        echo "journal: " . $name . "\n";
        echo "if: " . $impactFactor . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Papers do not have impact factors. Do you mean for a journal?

Comment: Yes, a journal. I'm keeping track of all the academics in my department. I have list of publications for each academic and we can see who is publishing and who isn't. Now I want to get the impact of each academic. It would be great if there was a web service.

Comment: The impact factor of the journals an individual publishes in does not in any way give you their individual "impact"

Comment: If you are looking at the impact of **individuals**, you should look into getting the h-index of the academic instead of the impact factor of his journals. Google Scholar is your friend here. *(not saying this is a great idea, just answering the question)*

Comment: @xLeitix Unfortunately google scholar doesn't have an API.

Comment: It's possible to get altmetrics.

You can use the crossref API to turn citations into DOIs.  You can then throw these DOIs at the impact story API to get back altmetrics (but not impact factor)

Comment: Usually, the best equipped and qualified people to do this kind of work are the university's librarians. Specifically, they typically subscribed to receive the latest impact factors in the form of a spreadsheet. You could obtain this data from your library and use it in the script you want.

Comment: If you have solved your question, you should [add it as an answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) rather than editing it in as an update to the question, so that it's easier for future readers to identify as an answer. (And note that you *can* accept your own answer)

Comment: Note that the database of the site you mention is 'reverse generated' from information gathered on the web. It is also incomplete (several of the good journals in my field are not listed).

Comment: So what good journal isn't listed then?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to search the publisher of the impact factor's website which indexes the journals or even the journal's websites themselves in which their IF is written. However, if I want to answer your question; I found one website which may help you the way you want to search for impact factors.

I searched over the net and only found [Impact Factor Search website](http://www.impactfactorsearch.com) in which you have to enter the journal's full title (seems simpler than uploading the bibtex information) and by clicking on the provided link, a search list will appear to you. You then have to choose the name of the journal you want to get information about and in the output's window you will have the following information:

```
JOURNAL NAME:

ABBREVIATION:

IMPACT FACTOR 2013:
```

The website currently prints the most up-to-date IF, for the year 2013, and is ready to support IF for the year 2014 too [as the latest data become available](http://www.impactfactorsearch.com/newdata.html) .

Comment: ImpactFactorSeach.com is now squatted, no use at all unfortunately

Comment: @DuncanMcGregor So bad... I remember that at the time I was writing this answer, the website was working perfectly with a very nice graphical design and good functionality.